# Writing individual words per Excel cell using csv in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a plain .txt document that I'm splitting up into individual words, appending them into a list, and then I'm trying to write that list into an Excel file so that each word is a new cell in the file. No matter what I do though, my code keeps taking all the words in the string and puts them in one cell, instead of splitting it by word like I'd intended. If you can help, could you also help explain why your solution works or why mine was wrong? Thanks!

Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
import csv

list_of_words = []

with open('ExampleText.txt', 'r') as ExampleText:
    for line in ExampleText:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
            list_of_words.append(word)
            print("Done!")
    print("Also done!")

with open('Gazete.csv', 'wb') as WordsFromText:
    writer = csv.writer(WordsFromText, delimiter=' ', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(list_of_words)
```

Comment: Is your delimiter a space? Why not use comma or ; or tab? Also how do you import it in Excel afterward? If you just double-lick it's unlikely to word. If you import it through "data" tab, then "from text" and mark " " (a space) as your delimiter it should owrk.

Comment: You say: "my code keeps taking all the words in the string and puts them in one cell" ... how do you know that? Have you tried opening the output file in a text editor?

Comment: Hi, yes, in Excel, or a text editor it shows up as one line like this: ⱁⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬⰬ਍ (Even imported through the data tab in Excel.)

Answer (score 1):

Excel defaults to comma or tab delimited when opening from CSV regardless of what your delimiter was set to during the export from Python. Try using a delimiter of ',' if you are trying to put these words into a separate cell in the same row.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need to specify delimiter if you specify a dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the delimiter parameter from your call to csv.writer.

```
writer = csv.writer(WordsFromText, dialect='excel')
```

You don't need one when a dialect is specified.

Comment: You don't need to specify a string to break on. Docs: If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator

Comment: Thanks.  Did not know that.  Updated my answer.